# pst-plot graph offset on page when graph has non-zero origin

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

This question relates to the use of pst-plot with datasets that have x axis values starting from a positive number for example x = 0.5 -> 0.8.

In the case below, on two separate computers both running Texlive (pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)), the dvi output is shifted to the right by about the width of the graph.

If DVIPS -E is used to extract the picture to an EPS file this too has extra white space on the left of the graph.

It's quite likely that this is a problem in which I don't understand the options I’m setting properly and the behaviour is expected.

Some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-eps,graphicx,pst-grad,amsmath,pst-all}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\readdata{\OPA}{transferCharacteristics.txt}
\readdata{\OPB}{transferCharacteristics2.txt}
\readdata{\OPC}{transferCharacteristics3.txt}
\readdata{\OPD}{transferCharacteristics4.txt}

\pslegend[lt]{\black\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 10~V\\
\red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 30~V\\
\green\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 50~V\\
\blue\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 70~V}

\psset{llx=0cm,lly=0cm, xAxisLabel={$V_{\mathrm{BE}}$ [V]}, xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3in}, yAxisLabel={$I_\mathrm{C}$ [A]}, yAxisLabelPos={-0.5in,c},ury=0.0cm,urx=0cm}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes,xticksize=0 0.20,yticksize=0 0.30,subticks=0, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.02, Oy=0, Ox=0.5](0.5,0)(0.5,0)(0.801,0.201){6cm}{5cm}
\pstScalePoints(1,1){}{}

\listplot[linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt]{\OPA}
\listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{\OPB}
\listplot[linecolor=green,linewidth=1pt]{\OPC} 
\listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt]{\OPD}

\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

where transferCharacteristics.txt etc. are in the form:

```
5.500000000000000e-001,2.631940e-005
5.512678809428449e-001,2.764127e-005
5.525386846531173e-001,2.903280e-005
5.538124178684922e-001,3.049784e-005
5.550890873421763e-001,3.204043e-005
5.563686998429440e-001,3.366487e-005
5.576512621551735e-001,3.537569e-005
```

and are each 153 lines in length.

The image below is a JPEG created from the EPS.
[image: example white space on left]

Everything is available from: http://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/randomstuff/pstplotwhitespace/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single image use documentclass `standalone`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
    \readdata{\OPA}{transferCharacteristics.txt}
    \readdata{\OPB}{transferCharacteristics2.txt}
    \readdata{\OPC}{transferCharacteristics3.txt}
    \readdata{\OPD}{transferCharacteristics4.txt}

    \pslegend[lt]{\black\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 10~V\\
    \red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 30~V\\
    \green\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 50~V\\
    \blue\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 70~V}
    \psset{llx=-1.5cm,lly=-1cm, xAxisLabel={$V_{\mathrm{BE}}$ [V]}, xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3in}, yAxisLabel={$I_\mathrm{C}$ [A]}, yAxisLabelPos={-0.5in,c},ury=0.0cm,urx=0cm}
    \begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes,xticksize=0 0.20,yticksize=0 0.30,
      subticks=0, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.02, Oy=0, Ox=0.5](0.5,0)(0.5,0)(0.801,0.201){6cm}{5cm}
    \listplot[linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt]{\OPA}
    \listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{\OPB}
    \listplot[linecolor=green,linewidth=1pt]{\OPC} 
    \listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt]{\OPD}
    \end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just in case you're wondering, this problem in my understanding has come about because I use Cirkuit. [http://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html](http://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html) Most of the time it works fine to preview and extract to EPS using the article class and a `\begin{TeXtoEPS}` and `\end{TeXtoEPS}` environment. That's why I thought the problem above worked ok with numbers starting from zero at the origin but not 0.55. It seems that your method with the standalone class is more general. I'll modify my Cirkuit back-end accordingly.

Comment: I've been unable to get Cirkuit to play ball even with the standalone class instead of article. I've filed bug report 339735 at [https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339735](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339735). I may get told off... we'll see.

Comment: I cannot see any advantage of using `circuitk` for creating an image. The preamble of the documents with `pst-eps` is totally outdated.

Comment: Fair enough... I only use it because I do a lot of electrical circuit diagrams as well. I will move my PSTricks coding to Kile, unless something better is suggested.

Comment: You should write to the maintainer of circuitk that they should update the templates.

Comment: Agreed, I will contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `preview` package plus `article` class instead of `standalone` class to get the same (based on our bare eyes) result.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt\relax % if you need 12pt border around the output


\begin{document}
    \readdata{\OPA}{transferCharacteristics.txt}
    \readdata{\OPB}{transferCharacteristics2.txt}
    \readdata{\OPC}{transferCharacteristics3.txt}
    \readdata{\OPD}{transferCharacteristics4.txt}

    \pslegend[lt]{\black\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 10~V\\
    \red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 30~V\\
    \green\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 50~V\\
    \blue\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 70~V}
    \psset{llx=-1.5cm,lly=-1cm, xAxisLabel={$V_{\mathrm{BE}}$ [V]}, xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3in}, yAxisLabel={$I_\mathrm{C}$ [A]}, yAxisLabelPos={-0.5in,c},ury=0.0cm,urx=0cm}
    \begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes,xticksize=0 0.20,yticksize=0 0.30,
      subticks=0, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.02, Oy=0, Ox=0.5](0.5,0)(0.5,0)(0.801,0.201){6cm}{5cm}
    \listplot[linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt]{\OPA}
    \listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{\OPB}
    \listplot[linecolor=green,linewidth=1pt]{\OPC} 
    \listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt]{\OPD}
    \end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]