# Unexpected result when converting image from DVI to EPS

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, conversion, eps, dvi-mode

This question follows on from a prior question but is separate and can stand alone.

The prior question is at [pst-plot graph offset on page when graph has non-zero origin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204800/pst-plot-graph-offset-on-page-when-graph-has-non-zero-origin).

This question is related to conversion of dvi to ps and subsequent inclusion of that ps in latex.

For example:

1) The code below is run through latex and dvi output is produced.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\readdata{\OPA}{transferCharacteristics.txt}
\readdata{\OPB}{transferCharacteristics2.txt}
\readdata{\OPC}{transferCharacteristics3.txt}
\readdata{\OPD}{transferCharacteristics4.txt}

\pslegend[lt]{\black\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 10~V\\
\red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 30~V\\
\green\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 50~V\\
\blue\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & 70~V}

\psset{llx=-1.5cm,lly=-1cm, xAxisLabel={$V_{\mathrm{BE}}$ [V]}, xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3in}, yAxisLabel={$I_\mathrm{C}$ [A]}, yAxisLabelPos={-0.5in,c},ury=0.0cm,urx=0cm}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes,xticksize=0 0.20,yticksize=0 0.30, subticks=0, Dx=0.1, Dy=0.02, Oy=0, Ox=0.5](0.5,0)(0.5,0)(0.801,0.201){6cm}{5cm}
\listplot[linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt]{\OPA}
\listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{\OPB}
\listplot[linecolor=green,linewidth=1pt]{\OPC} 
\listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt]{\OPD}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

2) DVIPS is used to convert the dvi output to postscript using

```
dvips -o test.ps test.dvi
```

at the command line. Viewing test.ps in Okular or similar looks similar to

[image: http://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/randomstuff/DVIPSweird/test.png]

There's a lot of white space (well transparent actually) and the image is upside down and mirrored. The image should, in my view, look like

[image: http://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/randomstuff/DVIPSweird/test.png]
<sub>(source: [iceamplifiers.co.uk](http://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/randomstuff/DVIPSweird/testdvi-ps-pdf-png.png))</sub>

which was produced by converting the dvi to the ps (above!) then converting the ps to pdf then converting the pdf to png (for web use).

Unsurprisingly using the ps in a latex document does not produce the desired result. Also unsurprisingly using the pdf that was generated from the ps in a pdflatex document works fine.

I'm not too worried about using latex over pdflatex or vice versa but I would like to know how the ps to pdf conversion stage manages to get the right looking picture in the pdf file and how I can make the ps file look like the pdf.

All files available from [http://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/randomstuff/DVIPSweird/](https://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/randomstuff/DVIPSweird/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to view the dvi output. It cannot show rotations and also sometimes not the correct image size. Use *always* the pdf output which should be upside down and cropped.

```
latex <file>
dvips -o <file>.ps <file>
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None <file>.ps
```

However, the easiest way is to run `xelatex`, it does the conversion process in the background. But it needs a ghostscript version not younger than 9.10

Comment: The output I'm showing in the first image in the question is the ps output, is that the same as viewing the dvi output? By what method could I use `latex` and include the image as eps (just for curiosity)?

Comment: no, the ps output should be correct. But sometimes the viewers which uses ghostscript are too clever and rotate images where they shouldn't. If you want to be on the safe side use always the pdf output.